# Visual Studio Code source control is full

Tags: git, visual-studio, version-control, visual-studio-code

I just started using GitHub and I think I messed up something in Visual Studio Code. As you can see on the [Source Control screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9PaZ.jpg) it has 5000 changes and when I try to use Discard all changes or Unstage all changes functions, this error pops up:

```
Git: warning: failed to remove AppData/Local/Comms/UnistoreDB/USS.jtx: Invalid argument
```

This problem only occurs when I open one specific project, but never used any git commands on this project.

Comment: Have you tried the command line? If you **really** want to get rid of all uncommitted changes you can execute `git reset --hard` **BUT BE AWARE**, it will **delete** all your changes that you have not committed, you can **not** get the changes back afterwards.

Comment: Just did, nothing has changed.

Comment: Does `git diff` or `git diff --staged` tell you anything? If all the files have "changed" for no reason, did you mess with line endings? Did you add or change system or repository settings for this, as an example? Added or edited a `.gitattributes` file perhaps?

Comment: No, I haven't tried many commands yet. Mostly just pulling, pushing and commiting some stuff. But might have done something that caused this mess. I haven't added or edited .gitattributes either.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you located the git repo in the wrong directory. The root path for the git repo seems `C:\Users\bekas\AppData\Local`, while the project you want to version controlled by git seems in a subfolder of `C:\Users\bekas\AppData\Local`. To trouble shooting the issue, you can use below steps:

- **Check the root git repo path**

  In terminal window, use the command `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`. The output path is where the git repo located. If you don’t need the directory to be version controlled by git, go to the directory and delete the `.git` folder.
- **Check the root of your project path**

  Go to the root directory where your project located, and check if there has `.git` folder (managed by git repo). If not, use `git init` to manage this project by git repo.

Comment: That's what I thought at first, but couldn't find .git folder, though my problem was solved when I updated VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

navigate to your user, unhide the files in the disk and delete the.git folder.

Comment: And lose anything stored therein? Dangerous, particularly without explanation of when/why one should do this