# Just installed Visual Studio Code and it already has 5000 commits

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I just downloaded VSC to try the editor, but when I opened the git tab, it showed I already have 5000 commits. When I select 'Discard all Changes' nothing happens. It gives me this notification every time I open the editor.[image: notification]

I searched for the issue and found [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45675757/visual-studio-code-source-control-is-full) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46656079/visual-studio-code-git-wont-discard-files), but I wasn't able to solve the problem. I was wondering if this is normal or if I should do something to get rid of them.

Thanks!

Comment: I think it is due to node modules you have installed for running the project.Ignore it. I hope it helps

Comment: It looks like you accidentally created a Git repo at `~/Desktop/`. Remove `~/Desktop/.git` and start over.

Comment: @jsageryd It shows me the same error when I am in a different folder. I am in a directory called locallibrary and it shows me the same error with this path '/Users/mithu/Desktop/PracticeCode/locallibrary'.

Comment: Is there a `.git` directory there too by any chance?

Comment: No there isn't. And there wasn't any on my desktop either. @jsageryd

Comment: The '.git' folder is probably hidden. Are you sure you could see hidden files and folders?